# i.spectral tool error

Tags: grass-gis, digital-image-processing, change-detection, land-use

system description: Windows7 32 bıt OS, Grass GIS 7.0.0 Gnuplot 5.0

Solution attempt 01:

On the basis of following thread, commented out said path check lines from i.spectral.py script:
https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2006-June/034856.html

Solution attempt 02:

Set GRASS_GNUPLOT=C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin (installed location of gnuplot.exe) throgh
settings-> Grass Working Environment-> Change Settings (g.gisenv)
based upon recommendations from the following discussion:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Error-in-windows-version-of-i-spectral-td5018720.html

However, still unable to run i.spectral. Following error message appears in command output. Any workaround?

Command:

> i.spectral -g --verbose
>   raster=ATMS_B1@Target,ATMS_B2@Target,ATMS_B3@Target
>   coordinates=202334.820717,2645169.44223 output=SPCTRL

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.0.0/scripts/i.spectral.py", line 241, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.0.0/scripts/i.spectral.py", line 234, in main
    draw_gnuplot(what, xlabels, output, img_fmt,
coord_legend)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.0.0/scripts/i.spectral.py", line 144, in draw_gnuplot
    grass.call(['gnuplot', plotfile])
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.0.0\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 72, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.0.0\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 56, in __init__
    raise OSError
OSError
```